# "SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6cf0e48, pid=7543, tid=7604" error while starting Android Studio 3.6.1 for Linux

Tags: java, android, linux

I just installed openjdk-9 on my Linux 18.4 with terminal (all informations about software avaible below) to start Android Studio 3.6.1 (the tar.gz file extracted).

Here what I get when I start the .sh file of Android Studio (did ./studio.sh in terminal):

```
-----
JRE 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src i386 by Oracle Corporation
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-i386
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6db2e48, pid=10957, tid=11023
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, concurrent mark sweep gc, linux-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x18e48]  JNU_GetEnv+0x18
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/teo/android-studio/bin/core.10957)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/teo/java_error_in_STUDIO_10957.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

(follow link for the log created in the home directory after) : [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IjOtTM05847UVF29TwZWNm1wxRtXT8uj/view?usp=sharing)

Can someone help me ?

As a newbie here, I don't know what to put more as informations :/

My software's informations :

```
                                       teo@Teo
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMmds+.        OS: Mint 18.3 sylvia
 MMm----::-://////////////oymNMd+`     Kernel: i686 Linux 4.15.0-122-generic
 MMd      /++                -sNMd:    Uptime: 57m
 MMNso/`  dMM    `.::-. .-::.` .hMN:   Packages: 2977
 ddddMMh  dMM   :hNMNMNhNMNMNh: `NMm   Shell: bash 4.3.48
     NMm  dMM  .NMN/-+MMM+-/NMN` dMM   Resolution: 1440x900
     NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   DE: KDE5
     NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   WM: KWin
     NMm  dMM  .mmd  `mmm   yMM. dMM   GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
     NMm  dMM`  ..`   ...   ydm. dMM   Icon Theme: breeze
     hMM- +MMd/-------...-:sdds  dMM   Font: Noto Sans Regular
     -NMm- :hNMNNNmdddddddddy/`  dMM   CPU: Intel Pentium D CPU 3.00GHz @ 2.992GHz
      -dMNs-``-::::-------.``    dMM   GPU: ATI RC410
       `/dMNmy+/:-------------:/yMMM   RAM: 1194MiB / 1755MiB
          ./ydNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  
             \.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

EDIT: I tried another app which use the JRE, GeoGebra, and got the same error. I can see startup logo of GeoGebra but it suddenly closes and give me the same error above.

Comment: The java is built for the i386. Is this a 32-bit version?

Comment: Yes, this is a 32-bit version.@NomadMaker

Comment: Is Android Studio a 32-bit version?

Comment: This is where I don't really know, I just installed the tar.gz file from the official website. @NomadMaker It might be 32-bit version bcz I saw the logo of Android Studio when I started it from terminal.